# Copying files from AWS S3 to Snowflake Table - Copy executed with 0 files processed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
COPY INTO mycsvtable
FROM @my_csv_stage/tutorials/dataloading/
PATTERN='.*test.dat'
on_error = 'skip_file';

COPY INTO mycsvtable
FROM @my_csv_stage/tutorials/dataloading/
PATTERN='.*test.*[.]dat'
on_error = 'skip_file';
```

I have multiple files named test in AWS S3 Bucket. I'm trying to copy those files to Snowflake table. When I run the COPY command, it's getting failed. I'm getting the error stating - Copy executed with 0 files processed.

Tried the above scripts. Looks like I need to make changes in the pattern. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ingest all files in the stage, you don't need to use pattern clause - you can just remove it.

If you need to specify the files by pattern, list the files and make sure that you have the files:

```
ls @my_csv_stage/tutorials/dataloading/
```

Lastly, maybe these files are already ingested, so you can also try using "FORCE = TRUE" option.

[https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#:~:text=the%20desired%20output.-,FORCE%20%3D%20TRUE%20%7C,-FALSE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#:%7E:text=the%20desired%20output.-,FORCE%20%3D%20TRUE%20%7C,-FALSE)

```
COPY INTO mycsvtable
FROM @my_csv_stage/tutorials/dataloading/
on_error = 'skip_file' force=true;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Atil. If I want to copy similar files like test_1.dat, test2.dat,test_3.dat, can I use PATTERN='.*test.dat'. If I want to copy only the dat files can I use any regexp?

Comment: can you try this one? PATTERN='.*test.*dat'.

Comment: Looks like it's working. Thanks! How can we use regexp pattern matching to select all the dat files?

Comment: I think PATTERN='.*\\.dat' should select all .dat files

Comment: @SherinShaziya you are welcome! Pls, don't forget to mark the answer correct if it's correct. ;)